# How to create a grab method in Java that deals with Generics and Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, object, generics

So, I am creating a generic data structure named "Sack". In this, I add items to a sack, grab a random item, see if it's empty, or dump out its contents etc. Also, I'm creating it to expand to hold as many items as needed.

I need to create a grab method that should randomly remove and return an item from the sack. If no items are present, it should return null.

My code is the following:

```
public class Sack<E>
{
public static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
private E [] elementData;
private int size;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Sack()
{
    elementData = (E[]) new Object[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Sack(int capacity)
{
    if(capacity < 0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("capacity " + capacity);
    }
    this.elementData = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
}
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    if(size == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
public void add(E item)
{
    int index = size++;
    if(size >= elementData.length-1)
    {
        elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);
    }
    elementData[index] = item;
}
public E [] dump()
{
   E [] E2 = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);
   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
      elementData[i] = null;
   }
   size = 0;
    return E2;
}
```

My grab method is right here.

```
public E [] grab()
{
    E [] E2 = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);
    return elementData;
}
```

It is incorrect, I receive an error when I run my tests stating AssertionFailedError: grab is not working correctly (check with empty sack) 
==>

`Expected: null`

`Actual : [Ljava.lang.Object;@76908cc0`

My tests are right here, I cannot modify my tests, only the code provided as there is an error there, I need help on what I previously stated:

the grab method should randomly remove and return an item from the sack. If no items are
present, it should return null

Therefore, here are my tests:

```
 @Test
 public void testGrab()
 {
    assertNull(s.grab(), "grab is not working correctly (check with empty sack)");
    Random rand = new Random();
    int numElements = rand.nextInt(9) + 1;
    Integer[] setElementData = new Integer[10];
    ArrayList<Integer> expectedElements = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int randElement;
    for(int i=0; i<numElements; ++i) {
        randElement = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;
        if(!expectedElements.contains(randElement)) {
            setElementData[i] = randElement;
            expectedElements.add(randElement);
        } else {
            --i;
        }
    }
    try {
        elementData.set(s, setElementData);
        size.set(s, numElements);
        for(int i=0; i<numElements; ++i) {
            expectedElements.remove(s.grab());
            assertEquals(numElements-i-1, size.get(s), "grab is not working correctly (check size usage)");
        }
        assertEquals(0, expectedElements.size(), "grab is not working correctly (check size usage)");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fail("grab is not working correctly");
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any solutions for my grab method on how to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why your grab method returns an array instead of a single element. I can suggest you a different approach

```
public class Sack<E> {
    private final static int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
    private final static float REALLOC_FACTOR = 1.5f;
    private E[] elementData;
    private int size;

    public Sack() {
        this(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Sack(int capacity) {
        if(capacity <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("capacity " + capacity);
        elementData = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }
    public void add(E item) {
        int index = size++;
        if(size > elementData.length-1)
            elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, (int)(size*REALLOC_FACTOR));
        elementData[index] = item;
    }
    public E [] dump() {
       E [] E2 = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);
       Arrays.fill(elementData, null);
       size = 0;
       return E2;
    }
    public E grab() {
        if(size == 0)
            return null;
        int index = (int)(Math.random()*size);
        E element = elementData[index];
        elementData[index] = elementData[size-1];
        elementData[size-1] = null;
        size--;
        return element;
    }
}
```

The idea behind this grab method is to select a random index *rand* (from 0 to effectiveSize-1) and to return this element, but before we have to swap this element with the last element (the element with index effectiveSize-1) and reduce the effective size. I have used Math.rand() because when it is first called, it creates a single new pseudorandom-number generator and then this generator is used thereafter for all calls to this method.

Note: I've also added a realloc factor to avoid the array realloc for each element, after the array is saturated.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at it in a bit and report back to you.

Comment: Alright, so I've tried this, and I receive an error when trying to return element. It's suppose to be a type E [] and what's being found is simply just a E.

Comment: Please explain what the grab method has to do because it is not clear: you said that the grab method should randomly remove and return an item from the sack, so this method must not return an array but just one element.

Comment: The grab method should randomly remove and return an item from the sack. If no items are present, it should return null.

Comment: Thank you, I made a mistake myself in the code. This works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer broken down a little more simply. I give credit to @Mirko Alicastro.

```
public E grab()
{
    if(size == 0)
        return null;
    int index = (int) (Math.random() * size);
        E element = elementData[index];
        elementData[index] = elementData[size - 1];
        elementData[size - 1] = null;
        size--;

    return element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of solving this method,

```
public E grab()
{
      if(isEmpty())
      {
         return null;
      }
      Random rand = new Random();
      int i = rand.nextInt(size);
      E item = elementData[i];
      remove(i);
      return item;
}
```